# Get child pages in get_pages function

Tags: pages

I know it has been asked many times on this website but I can't really get it to work with those examples.

This is my function so far:

```
$city_ids = get_pages( 
    array(
        "hierarchical" => 0, 
        "sort_column" => "menu_order", 
        "sort_order" => "desc", 
        "meta_key" => "country", 
        "meta_value" => $atts['country']
    )
);
```

This works. It gives me the page I want (Verhuizen naar Nederland), but I now need to child pages. It has three pages. See (There is one more):

[image]

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for, objects, ids, html, ... ?

Comment: @birgire I want id's. I will use get_field later on from the ACF plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `get_page_children` available for this purpose, have a look on the documentation and examples.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children

Comment: I think I'm the stupid one but I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using WP_Query inside the loop that displays the cities / parents and populate $id with e.g. $city->ID / $post->ID:

```
$children = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        "post_parent" => $id
    )
);
```